# Inheritance and init method in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, init

I'm begginer of python. I can't understand inheritance and `__init__()`.

```
class Num:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.n1 = num

class Num2(Num):
    def show(self):
        print self.n1

mynumber = Num2(8)
mynumber.show()
```

RESULT: `8`

This is OK. But I replace `Num2` with

```
class Num2(Num):
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.n2 = num*2
    def show(self):
        print self.n1,self.n2
```

RESULT: `Error. Num2 has no attribute "n1".`

In this case, how can `Num2` access `n1`?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

In the first situation, `Num2` is extending the class `Num` and since you are not redefining the special method named `__init__()` in `Num2`, it gets inherited from `Num`.

> When a class defines an `__init__()`
>   method, class instantiation
>   automatically invokes `__init__()` for
>   the newly-created class instance.

In the second situation, since you are redefining `__init__()` in `Num2` you need to explicitly call the one in the super class (`Num`) if you want to extend its behavior.

```
class Num2(Num):
    def __init__(self,num):
        Num.__init__(self,num)
        self.n2 = num*2
```

Comment: Your citation isn't sufficient to explain why , when not defining a ``__init__`` method in a derived-class, it gets inherited. It is because _" if a requested attribute is not found in the class, the search proceeds to look in the base class."_ (doc)

Comment: I'm sorry... that's basicly how inheritance works... if you inherit a class, you get the whole package, so, everything in the superclass exists in the subclass. But, if you redefine a method, it gets overriden... that's what's up in your code.

Comment: @mario-duarte any reason why this would be better than `super(Num2, self).__init__(num)`?

Comment: I just switched from the solution proposed in this answer to using `super`, and my program now loads a few seconds faster. No idea why.

Comment: `super` is supposed to be helpful when using multiple inheritance. For single inheritance its benefits are not obvious.

Comment: This is the only way to make it work with old-style classes in Python 2.

Answer (score 47):

When you override the init you have also to call the init of the parent class

```
super(Num2, self).__init__(num)
```

[Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super)

Comment: super(Num2,self).__init__(num)

Answer (score 27):

A simple change in Num2 class like this:

```
super().__init__(num)
```

It works in python3.

```
class Num:
        def __init__(self,num):
                self.n1 = num

class Num2(Num):
        def __init__(self,num):
                super().__init__(num)
                self.n2 = num*2
        def show(self):
                print (self.n1,self.n2)

mynumber = Num2(8)
mynumber.show()
```

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow. Even though this isn't the answer to the question it's helpful.  Sometimes the answers people post are the answers to the question that people should have been asking. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't call `Num.__init__` , the field "n1" never gets created. Call it and then it will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:
[Can I collect and merge different answers into an accepted one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306625/can-i-collect-and-merge-different-answers-into-an-accepted-one/306636#306636)

I am creating a wiki answer collecting input from above two latest answers: 
Answer with [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255778/8395964) by Sacchit Jaiswal & Tom Jelen 
Answer with [reason or why it's needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166539/8395964) by Mauro Rocco

---

When you override the init you have also to call the init of the parent class 
[Understanding Python super() with __init__() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super)

```
super(Num2, self).__init__(num)
```

It works in python3.

```
class Num:
        def __init__(self,num):
                self.n1 = num

class Num2(Num):
        def __init__(self,num):
                super().__init__(num)
                self.n2 = num*2
        def show(self):
                print (self.n1,self.n2)

mynumber = Num2(8)
mynumber.show()
```