# Trouble understanding a line of code in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to learn `PyQt` on my own from `rapid gui programming with python and qt` and having trouble understanding the `meaning/requirement` of below line of code mentioned in one of the example in the book.

```
class Form(QDialog):

        def __init__(self,parent=None):
                super(Form,self).__init__(parent) # Trouble understanding here
```

So, my question is what is the need of `super(Form,self).__init__(parent)` or what purpose it is trying to full fill [in this code](http://pastie.org/3937058).

Comment: Actually `__init__()` in this situation appears rather pointless... Is this the ONLY code present in the method?

Comment: No, I have attached the complete code http://pastie.org/3937058

Comment: Ah, I see. The purpose of `super(...)...` here is to call QDialog's constructor.

Comment: @JoelCornett: But why are we calling the constructor of QDialog what purpose it will full fill.

Comment: `QDialog` is a base class for dialogs. `QDialog.__init__()` contains all the code necessary to produce a new QDialog object. Since `Form` "overwrites" the original `QDialog.__init__()` with it's own `__init__()`, it needs to explicitly call `QDialog.__init__()` to ensure that that code is executed.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166473/inheritance-and-init-method-in-python

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [the documentation of `super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by getattr() except that the type itself is skipped.

So basically this line of code:

```
super(Form,self).__init__(parent)
```

finds the "closest" set `__init__()` method in classes from which current class (`Form`) is inheriting and initiates `self` object using this method and passing `parent` as the first argument.

Comment: I think he is trying to ask why are we passing `parent` in the constructor as an argument and what role it will play in relation to `PyQt`.

Comment: Yes, @RanRag is right I know what `super` does but why are we passing `parent` as an argument.

Comment: @Noob: You're passing parent as an argument in case you need to set the Form to be a child of another window. Notice that the default is None.