# How to remove redundancy of subclasses?

Tags: python-3.x

I have created a class `Character` and a subclass `Player`. I want to create an instance of the `Player` subclass but specify the self.variables during instantiation.

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = None
        self.Name = None
        self.Colour = None

class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self, ID, Name, Colour):
        self.ID = ID
        self.Name = Name
        self.Colour = Colour
        self.Karma = 0
        self.Charisma = 0
        self.Strength = 0
        self.Intelligence = 0
```

I can easily create an instance by using `Player("tutorial_guy", "Tutorial Ted", "Green")` but then that defeats the whole point of a subclass because of how the subclass `Player` is set up. How would I make the variables of `ID`, `Name` and `Colour` be set in `Character` but still instantiated the same way?

Comment: Are you asking how to reuse the parent class constructor in the child class?

Comment: what is `NPC` you described in the question? What you are describing is simply the basic concept of inheritance. Your `Character` init method should take the required arguments and assign them, and then the `Player` init will call `super()` with those arguments to reuse the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheritance and init method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166473/inheritance-and-init-method-in-python)

Comment: My question is based around using `super()`, I don't know how to implement it

Comment: @Tomerikoo I just posted an answer to that effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to subclass `Character` if it doesn't really do anything. So let's make it set `ID, Name, Colour` and then use `super()` to call its `__init__` method.

(UpperCamelCase names should be reserved for classes, so I'm using `id_, name, colour` -- `id_` to avoid shadowing the builtin `id()`.)

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, id_, name, colour):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.name = name
        self.colour = colour

class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self, id_, name, colour):
        super().__init__(id_, name, colour)
        self.karma = 0
        self.charisma = 0
        self.strength = 0
        self.intelligence = 0
```

p.s. I'm just getting into OOP so please lmk if I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Include the attribute as a class `Character()` inside `Player()`:

```py
class Character():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID = None
        self.Name = None
        self.Colour = None
    def setAttributes(self, ID, Name, Colour) :
        self.ID = ID
        self.Name = Name
        self.Colour = Colour
    def showAttributes(self) :
        print(self.ID)
        print(self.Name)
        print(self.Colour)

class Player(Character):
    def __init__(self, ID, Name, Colour):
        self.char = Character()
        self.char.setAttributes( ID, Name, Colour )
        self.ID = ID
        self.Name = Name
        self.Colour = Colour
        self.Karma = 0
        self.Charisma = 0
        self.Strength = 0
        self.Intelligence = 0

a = Player("me", "Tim", "red")

### OUTPUT
>>> a.showAttributes()
me
Tim
red
```

if you want to keep the same initialization configuration, otherwise you can specify the `Character` char at `__init__` etc