# Why does it have double __init__ function?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have question for the below code, I could understand that the code has `def __init__` function, it is necessary to initialize the Frame class, but I still could not understand that why we need to have `wx.Frame.__init__` ? Is it necessary to initialize the wx.Frame object?

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
     def __init__(self, title):
         wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(350,200))
 
app = wx.App(redirect=True)
top = Frame("Hello World")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166473/inheritance-and-init-method-in-python) answer you question ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to initialize the wx.Frame object?

**Exactly**. The `wx.Frame.__init__()` is a constructor for a base class. Class `Frame` inherits from `wx.Frame` and constructor of `Frame` automatically calls the constructor of `wx.frame`.

Have a look at this:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    print('Foo was created!')

class Bar(Foo):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__() # It's the same as Foo.__init__
    print('Bar was created!')

B = Bar()
# Output:
# Foo was created!
# Bar was created!
```

The `super()` ***returns a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent class.***

For more see: [Built-in Functions - super](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, you are creating object of `Frame` Class. that takes attributes which are defined in the `Frame` which is defined in wx module.

When you use `wx.Frame.__init__` it loads wx module, go to Frame class of that module and run its init function, so all the attributes that are in init of module Frame class get stored on the class which is on your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The local `Frame` class inherits all the properties of wx.Frame. I don't believe it's necessary to write `__init__` but in this case:

```
top = Frame("Hello World")
```

is similar to something like

```
top = wx.Frame(None, title="Hello World", size=(350,200))
```

Calling `wx.Frame.__init__()` isn't necessary but it helps setup the default size for the frame and some other parameters behind the scenes in your new `Frame` class.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the **init** fucntion in the Frame class, its overriding the inherited class **init** function.

If you want to extend the functionality of inherited class, you need to initialize that class objects also.

```
import wx
class Frame(wx.Frame):
    pass
```

this will be same as above class, as **init** is not defined in subclass, inherited class **init** will be used.